# Stars and Bars Computation With Distinct Stars

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a standard Stars and Bars problem with a restriction that each partition has at least one star.

With $n$ indistinguishable items and $k$ buckets, we can compute this by $n-1 \choose k-1$ 
But what if the items were distinct? 
Would it be: 
$n! {n-1 \choose k-1}$ ?

Comment: The $n!$ overcounts permutations of elements in the same set.

Comment: are the buckets distinguishable?

Comment: My mistake, the buckets are distinct

Comment: For problems like this, it's nice to keep a chart of the "twelvefold way" to count the number of mappings from N to K based on whether the elements of N are distinct, whether the elements of K are distinct, and whether the mapping needs to be surjective, injective, or unrestricted.

Comment: This scenario is what the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) are for.  Otherwise, you need to use something like inclusion-exclusion as in Michael's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since each object can go into one of $k$ buckets, there are $k^n$ ways to distribute the $n$ objects.  In this case however, one of the buckets might be empty.  Now, use inclusion/exclusion to reduce the number of buckets.